# meaning of trenchantly in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm not sure what "trenchantly" means in this sentence:

> While the rest of the firm gradually acquired a new persona, mortgages remained more trenchantly the same.

Here is the definition I found of trenchant:

> 1. vigorous or incisive in expression or style.
>      "she heard angry voices, not loud, yet certainly trenchant"
> 2. archaicliterary
>      (of a weapon or tool) having a sharp edge.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Although one of the meanings of [trenchantly](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trenchant?s=t) is "vigorously, energetically," which by  some stretch might fit the context, I suspect the author thought that *trenchant* had a lot more to do with a word with a similar root: *entrenched*. Beyond this etymological connection, however, the two words have nothing to do with one another.

*Trenchant* ultimately derives from Old French *trenchant*, present participle of *trenchier*, to cut. Today, if someone is Paris wants to slice up a chicken or roast, they use the verb *trancher*. Thus the metaphoric cutting and incisive character of *trenchant*.

*[Entrench](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/entrench?s=t)*, though from the same root, didn't follow the same route into the language. It is a native English word derived from *trench*, i.e., something dug (cut) into the ground, especially for defensive purposes. An *entrenched* position is defensive and unmoving, "dug in" for battle.

Thus while other departments gradually changed, mortgages didn't move at all, but maintained an entrenched position, remaining the same.

Comment: @KarlG  So if the author used the word "trenchantly" to mean more like "entrenched", doesn't "trenchantly" and "the same" sound redundant?

Comment: No, it just means he used the wrong word. _Entrenched_ and _status quo_ go together quite well.